# Can the Microsoft Hyper-V Server 2012 (standalone) run VDI? (Which needs an AD)

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server-2012, vdi

I have not used the standalone (and free) product, Microsoft Hyper-V Server 2012.
Initially I thought this was the installer for Hyper-V on an existing Windows box, but as I understand it, it's a hyper-visor itself (has mini host OS).

Since you cannot add roles and features to this standalone server, can you run a VDI? (with RDS etc.).

My issue is that the VDI requires a domain to join to, and if this server is standlone and has no domain in it's network, can it provide the domain services to do so? I'm running a VDI on a single machine, which also plays the AD DC role for my AD needs.

Are there other things that may prohibit the standalone from being a proper VDI?
I am assuming that this standalone is like a Server 2012 Core + Hyper-V role and does not allow other roles.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I loaded Hyper-V Server 2012 standalone and also found out some hidden secrets for VDI/RDS.

It turns out that:

```
Running a Domain Controller with Remote Desktop Services is not supported, as of 2012. 
Previously it was simply not recommended.
```

So even if I could install the AD DS role and have the machine promoted as the DC, I wouldn't be able to install VDI/RDS on it.

The DC must be located on another machine and the VDI host must simply join the domain.

Also:

```
Hyper-V Server 2012 standalone is meant only as a Hyper-V, without any additional roles and features.
It runs as a Server-Core and works great if you have a managed VDI and need another host, but not to set up a VDI.
```

Hope this helps out someone in the future.